# Given an array 'a' and an integer 'x', arrange the elements of the (in place) such that all the elements <x come before all the elements >='x'

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, linked-list

Also, preserve the original relative order of elements in both the groups (i.e elements smaller than 'x' form one group and elements equal to or greater than 'x' form another group. The relative order should be maintained in both the groups.)

**Example 1:-**

> a={2,6,3,5,1,7}
>
> x=5
>
> Output : 2 3 1 6 5 7

```
All the elements smaller than 5 come before 5 and the relative order of the moved elements is 
   preserved (2,3,1) & (6,5,7)
```

**Example 2:-**

> a={1,4,2,5,3}
>
> x=4
>
> output : 1 2 3 4 5

The original question was for a singly linked list . I wrote the algorithm for an array and I wanted to know if it can be ported to the linked list variation. Also, is there a better way of doing this?

```
   #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void swap(vector<int> &a, int i, int j)
{
    int i2 = i;
    int x = a[j];
    int temp1 = a[i];
    int temp2;
    while (i < j)
    {
        temp2 = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = temp1;
        temp1 = temp2;
        i++;
    }
    a[i2] = x;
}

void solve(vector<int> &a, int num)
{
    int n = a.size();
    int i = 0, j = 1;
    while (j < n)
    {
        if (a[i] < num)
            i++;
        if (a[i] >= num && a[j] < num)
            swap(a, i, j);
        j++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a = {2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 7};
    int num = 5;
    solve(a, num);
    for (auto el : a)
        cout << el << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can create a vector from a linked list and vice versa, hence if you can sort one you can also sort the other.

Comment: Yeah, but that would be cheating as per the question. You were given the head of the linked list and the question wanted you to do everything in place.

Comment: using a solution that works is cheating but asking others for the solution is not. Hmmm...

Comment: The test is over now. I was just trying to solve the questions that I couldn't.

Comment: This is called [`partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) in `std`, and the possible implementation on that site works for both `vector` and `list` (among others). Depending on the exact requirements, you might want [`stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition)

Comment: @Caleth So, this would work on built in containers. A linked list defined using struct would not work. I guess the best way to do this would be to put the elements of a linked list into a vector and then run this algo on it and put it back.

Comment: @infernus-85 you need to write an iterator type for your linked-list

Comment: ([Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h))

Comment: Also [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: For a linked list, the problem would actually be easier than for arrays. Your algorithm is O(n**2); there is a O(n) simple solution for linked lists.

Comment: @Stef can you share the algorithm? Also, I know the bad practices, but it's faster and I mostly code for contests. I need to be as fast s possible and write as less code as possible.

Comment: @infernus-85 Actually, `using std::cout;` would have been faster than `using namespace std;` in that case.

Comment: @infernus-85 With linked list, there is no "in-place" constraint; just add the elements to two distinct lists depending on whether they're smaller or larger than x, then add a link from the end of the "smalls" list to the start of the "larges" list.

Comment: @Stef not faster in that sense. Faster in writing code.

Comment: @Stef I wasn't supposed to use another linked list. That I thought of at first. But, I guess copying elements from linked list to vector doesn't break that constraint.

Comment: @infernus-85 A linked list is a bunch of nodes with pointers. Just play around with the pointers; you don't need to allocate memory for new nodes.

Comment: @Stef Ah, I see. So, you would copy the elements in an array and then fill the LL with the nodes which are smaller than 'x' and then after that you fill elements equal to or greater than 'x'? Right? (everything sequentially of course)

Comment: No. I would not use any array. I think the whole point of the question is that you should not use any extra memory, except for a constant number of variables. No new arrays.

Comment: @Stef I'll try to think of a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with linked lists, the concept of swapping is not really useful for linked lists. Instead you would *move* nodes.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
    public:
    int value;
    Node * next;
    
    Node(int value, Node * next) {
        this->value = value;
        this->next = next;
    }

    Node(int value) {
        this->value = value;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }

    void print() {
        Node * node = this;
        while (node != nullptr) {
            std::cout << node->value << " -> ";
            node = node->next;
        }
        std::cout << "NULL\n";
    }

    Node * partition(int pivot) {
        if (this->next == nullptr) return this; // Quick exit
        Node * preHead = new Node(0); // Dummy
        Node * preMid = new Node(0, this); // Dummy
        Node * lessTail = preHead;
        Node * prev = preMid;
        while (prev->next) {
            Node * curr = prev->next;
            if (curr->value < pivot) {
                prev->next = curr->next; // remove curr
                lessTail->next = curr; // insert curr
                lessTail = curr; 
            } else {
                prev = curr; // keep curr where it is
            }
        }
        lessTail->next = preMid->next;
        delete preMid;
        Node * head = preHead->next;
        delete preHead;
        return head;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Construct the list from example #2
    Node * head = new Node(1,
                new Node(4,
                new Node(2,
                new Node(5,
                new Node(3)))));
    head->print();  // 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3 -> NULL
    head = head->partition(4);
    head->print();  // 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> NULL
    // ...    
}
```

This code uses two temporary node instances, because that makes the code a bit easier. But it is also possible to do it without those dummy nodes. In that case you must perform some nullpointer checks to see when to assign to a `next` property or to a `head` variable.